# Custom SSO powered wiki engine

Tags: wiki, authentication

We've set up our own internal SSO server ([keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/)) for one of our web applications. The SSO server accepts OpenID Connect, OAuth2 and SAML protocols. Now we are struggling with unifying the documentation part with the SSO system, so we want to find some wiki engine which has some plugin in order to grant the user access and even authorize him to see some specific content, using the permissions given by keycloak.

Is there an already built software (preferably open source) with this features? The [twiki SSO plugin](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/SsoLoginContrib) seems to suit my needs, but twiki itself seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using a web proxy such as [the Keycloak HTTP(S) proxy](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-installation-and-configuration/content/topics/proxy.html) to sit in front of any wiki you like? That way you don't require the actual software to support it, you just proxy the software and Keycloak provides Web and Access Management (WAM) capabilities to force authentication (and presumably seamless SSO) to specific URLs.